# How to get number of properties in System.Tuple, c#?

Tags: c#, tuples

I need to access by index `Tuple`'s property and if there is no property with that index I want to throw `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

For instance:

```
Tuple<T1, T2, T3>  // has 3 properties: Item1, Item2, Item3
```

So is there an way I can get number of properties in `Tuple`?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to make much sense. The code that consumes an instance of a tuple knows exactly how many items there are. Maybe you could elaborate on your scenario?

Comment: In any case, it sounds more like you should be using a List<> or an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var v = new Tuple<int, int, int>(1, 2, 3);
var count = v.GetType().GenericTypeArguments.Length;
```